# eslint warning is failing the gitlab CI

Tags: typescript, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using React with Typescript. Locally i configured `eslint` to treat unused variable as warning.

When i run `npm run build` locally it work, but in gitlab ci i'm getting this error :

```
 npm run build
> optimal-move@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.
Failed to compile.
[eslint] 
src/common/components/MAppBar/MAppBar.tsx
  Line 4:8:   'Divider' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
  Line 4:8:   'Divider' is defined but never used         @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

You can see the gitlab repo in question [here](https://gitlab.com/anesboz/optimal-move/-/tree/feature/ci-cd). Where `.eslintrc.js` and `.gitlab-ci.yml` are well configured to me.

How to tell Gitlab CI to ignore warning ??

*ps: i want to build in order to serve the app in gitlab pages*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your `CI` environment variable to false. See this line in the log you posted:

> Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.

To get GitLab CI to ignore this, you should set `CI = "false"` in the `variables` section of your '.gitlab-ci.yml' (https://gitlab.com/anesboz/optimal-move/-/blob/feature/ci-cd/.gitlab-ci.yml#L7)

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include quotes around `false` in a previous edit.

Comment: I struggled with this ("quotes") bug. Also it must be in `yml` file because eslint does not reconoize CI variable when put in `.eslintrc.js`